# Azure blob service Public access level is changing automatically from Private to Blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have this problem that *Azure Blob Service Public Access Level* is changing automatically back from **Private** to **Blob** after some time, usually after 30 mins.

So my scenario is that I am setting the *Public Access Policy* on Azure Portal from **Blob** to **Private**. After some time it changes back to **Blob**.

I don't see any activity being logged in the portal.

How can I investigate that?

How can I permanently set it to be *Private* ?

Comment: Are you clicking the save button after access policy modification?
Access policy can’t be changed until unless someone has modified. I would suggest you to check with your colleagues whoever has access to the storage account.

Comment: Yes, i am clicking on the Save Button and it stays Private for some time, even if I refresh the azure portal page. I asked and none of my colleagues have changed this setting... Is there any way to get the log of actions made on the portal?

Comment: @gringo_dave. Is there any time trigger job to change blob access policy? If regenerate account key is possible, I recommand that you could regenerate the storage account keys and have a try.